# Sha1Sum on kali.org

Tags: download, kali-linux, checksum, sha1

I am unable to download kali linux from their official website kali.org. I try to verify the sha1sum but all I get is invalid

https://gyazo.com/2e02792c685fbd2ebfd50e04fe218501.

Any ideas? I can verify sha1sums of other files from other websites but not kali's. I use Windows 8, firefox and a VPN. Sha1sum doesn't work on any file from kali.org.

[image]

Did the same test with torrent, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that the file you downloaded has 3.7KBs. The Kali Linux ISO you're trying to download has 2.9GBs.  A couple of things you can conclude from that are:

1. Your download is not completing, you're getting a partial file.
2. A partial file will not have the correct checksum, therefore the checksum is working as expected (failing to tell you that you have the wrong file).
3. A download of 2.9GBs shall take a lot longer (even on a very quick connection).

What you certainly need to to do is to download the complete file before checking the checksum.  Your download may be interrupted by the VPN or by the Kali Linux servers (they're servers maintained by Offensive Security after all).  The main reason such a download may be interrupted by both (VPN, and servers) is the number of parallel connections.  Limit your parallel connections to, say, 3 (three); or even, use the plain, single connection, download manager provided by browsers.

Reference:

- [Kali Linux download page](https://www.kali.org/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem by letting it download fully and checking the Sha1Sum afterwards.